# Show that $2$ sets have "the same number of elements"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B,C$ be nonempty sets. We will denote $B^A$ as the number of functions defined $f:A\to B$.

Show that $B^A\times C^A$ and $(B\times C)^A$ "have the same number of elements". (in my language this is called "echipotenta" but I don't know how to call it here) To be more explicit, what I mean is: both sets are "equally rich" in elements. How do you show that $2$ sets are "echipotent"?

Comment: The english equivalent of "echipotenta" is "equipotent".

Comment: By definition, two sets have the same number of elements if there is a bijection between them.

Comment: @Servaes Oh, I'm sorry.. I tried to google translate it but haven't found anything and  also Wikipedia the page in my language then convert it to English and and still haven't found a thing, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In general, the way you can proof two sets $X,Y$ are equipotent is by finding a bijection (i.e., a function that is injective and surjective) $h:X\to Y$ between them.

In this case, notice that an element of the set $(B\times C)^A$ must be a function $f:A\to B\times C$, and element by element it looks like $f(a)=(b,c)$. If we call $f_1(a)=b$ and $f_2(a)=c$ whenever $f(a)=(b,c)$, then there is a natural way to obtain an element of the set $B^A\times C^A$ associated to $f$, namely the ordered pair $(f_1,f_2)$.

If you can show that the assignment 
\begin{align*}
h:&(B\times C)^A\longrightarrow B^A\times C^A\\
&\ \ \ \ \ \ f\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \longmapsto h(f)=(f_1,f_2)
\end{align*}
is a bijection, you will be done.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show a bijection $f$ exists with $\operatorname{dom} f=B^A\times C^A,\,\operatorname{rang} f=(B\times C)^A$. The desired domain is the set of ordered pairs $(g,\,h)$, with $g$ ($h$) a function from $A$ to $B$ ($C$). Meanwhile, the desired range is the set of functions from $A$ to ordered pairs $(b,\,c)$ with $b\in B,\,c\in C$. So it suffices to define $f((g,\,h)):= x\mapsto (g(x),\,h(x))$.

Comment: Okay, so correct me if I'm wrong, but what you're saying is, is that $f:B^A\times C^A \to (B\times C)^A, f(g(x),h(x))=(g(x),h(x))$, where $g:A\to B$ and $h: A\to C$, is the desired bijection which proves the equipotence of the sets?

Comment: What is the intuition behind the chosen function?

Comment: and your $f$ is bijective because...?

Comment: @C.Cristi Injective because changing $g$ or $h$ changes the result for at least one $x$, surjective because any ordered pair can be split to reverse-engineer $g,\,h$. The intuition is: how do you pair pairs of functions with pair-valued functions?

Answer (score 1):

Let $F : B^A \times C^A \rightarrow (B\times C)^A$ be defined by

$$F((f,g)) : A \rightarrow(B \times C)$$ 
$$F((f,g)) (a) = (f(a),g(a))$$

for all $a \in A$.

$F$ is **injective**:

> All $(f_1,g_1),(f_2,g_2) \in B^A \times C^A$ with 
>   $$F((f_1,g_1)) = F((f_2,g_2))$$ 
>   implies that
>   $$(f_1(a),g_1(a)) = (f_2(a),g_2(a))$$
>   for all $a \in A$, by definition of the ordered pair. Thus,
>   $$(f_1,g_1) = (f_2,g_2)$$ so $F$ is injective.

F is **surjective**:

> If $h \in (B \times C)^A$, then define $(f,g)$ by 
>   $$ (f,g) = (\pi_1\circ h, \pi_2 \circ h)$$
>   where $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are the projections. See that
>   $$F((f,g))(a) = (f(a),g(a)) = (\pi_1(h(a)),\pi_2(h(a))) = h(a)$$
>   so $F((f,g)) = h$ and hence $F$ is surjective.

Thus $F$ is **bijective**, so the sets have the same size.

Comment: That is an awesome proof! What was the intuition behind it and why you picked that function that certain way?

Comment: For $(f,g) \in B^A \times C^A$ I know it's required that $F((f,g)) : A \rightarrow (B \times C)$. So, how would I define $F((f,g))$? I know that it takes an $a \in A$, and produces something in $B \times C$. What do I have to work with? I have $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : A \rightarrow C$, so from the domain and codomain of these maps alone, a first guess would be to write  $F((f,g))(a) = (f(a),g(a))$, and then I simply checked injectivity and surjectivity. The intuition came simply from the domain and codomain of the maps I had to work with.

Comment: Of course this style doesn't work in general, but it does offer some initial guesses and builds intuition for the map your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the projections $\pi_1:B\times C\rightarrow B$ and $\pi_2:B\times C\rightarrow C$ onto the components.

Then for a given function $f:A\rightarrow B\times C$, define $f_1=\pi_1 f$ and $f_2=\pi_2f$ with $f_1(a) = \pi_1 f(a)= \pi_1(b,c)=b$ and $f_2(a)=\pi_2f(a) = \pi_2(b,c)=c$.

The assignment $f\mapsto (\pi_1f,\pi_2f)$ provides the required bijection.

For instance, take $A=B=C=\{0,1\}$ and the function $f:A\rightarrow B\times C$ with $f(0)=(1,0)$ and $f(1)=(1,1)$.

Then $f_1(0) = \pi_1f (0) = \pi_1(1,0) = 1$ and $f_2(1)=\pi_2f(1) = \pi_2(1,1)=1$.

Moreover, $f_2(0) =\pi_2f(0) = \pi_2(1,0)=0$ and $f_2(1)=\pi_2f(1)=\pi_2(1,1)=1$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\pi_1f$?

Comment: Function composition

Comment: Okay and why $\pi_1 f(a)=\pi_1(b,c)$?

Comment: What I mean is, can you add more detail and maybe provide the intuition behind all this?

Comment: Added simple example.